# ejabberd server does not start because ``mod_shared_roster`` module fails to start

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-auth

I am trying to start an ejabberd server but when I run the command `ejabberdctl live` or `ejabberdctl foreground` I am getting an error.

The error states that the `mod_shared_roster` module cannot start, but the error reason is `undef` which doesn't help much.

I am new to ejabberd, I tried to change `hosts` value of `ejabberd.yml` (In ejabberd.yml file I changed `hosts - 'localhost'` to `hosts -'127.0.0.1'`) but found no success.

Here's the terminal output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------

IMPORTANT: ejabberd is going to start in LIVE (interactive) mode.
All log messages will be shown in the command shell.
You can interact with the ejabberd node if you know how to use it.
Please be extremely cautious with your actions,
and exit immediately if you are not completely sure.

To exit this LIVE mode and stop ejabberd, press:
  q().  and press the Enter key

--------------------------------------------------------------------
To bypass permanently this warning, add to ejabberdctl.cfg the line:
  EJABBERD_BYPASS_WARNINGS=true
Press return to continue


Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V9.0  (abort with ^G)
(ejabberd@localhost)1&gt; 00:22:49.650 [info] Application lager started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.655 [info] Application crypto started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.666 [info] Application sasl started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.682 [info] Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.682 [info] Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.729 [info] Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.732 [info] Application p1_utils started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.742 [info] Application fast_yaml started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.762 [info] Application fast_tls started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.781 [info] Application fast_xml started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.790 [info] Application stringprep started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.797 [info] Application xmpp started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.814 [info] Application cache_tab started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.824 [info] Application iconv started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.826 [info] Application jiffy started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:49.826 [info] Loading configuration from /usr/local/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml
00:22:50.951 [info] Application mnesia started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:51.055 [warning] module &apos;ejabberd_c2s&apos; doesn&apos;t export listen_opt_type/1
00:22:51.183 [info] Application inets started on node ejabberd@localhost
00:22:51.277 [warning] module &apos;mod_shared_roster&apos; doesn&apos;t export mod_opt_type/1
00:22:51.280 [critical] Problem starting the module mod_shared_roster for host 127.0.0.1 
 options: []
 error: undef
[{mod_shared_roster,start,[&lt;&lt;&quot;127.0.0.1&quot;&gt;&gt;,[]],[]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,4,[{file,&quot;src/gen_mod.erl&quot;},{line,199}]},
 {lists,foreach,2,[{file,&quot;lists.erl&quot;},{line,1338}]},
 {gen_mod,start_link,0,[{file,&quot;src/gen_mod.erl&quot;},{line,78}]},
 {supervisor,do_start_child,2,[{file,&quot;supervisor.erl&quot;},{line,365}]},
 {supervisor,start_children,3,[{file,&quot;supervisor.erl&quot;},{line,348}]},
 {supervisor,init_children,2,[{file,&quot;supervisor.erl&quot;},{line,314}]},
 {gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,&quot;gen_server.erl&quot;},{line,365}]}]
00:22:51.280 [critical] ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
Problem starting the module mod_shared_roster for host 127.0.0.1 
 options: []
 error: undef
[{mod_shared_roster,start,[&lt;&lt;&quot;127.0.0.1&quot;&gt;&gt;,[]],[]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,4,[{file,&quot;src/gen_mod.erl&quot;},{li

Crash dump is being written to: /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash_20200520-002248.dump...done
```

here are partial contents of .dump file

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.3
Wed May 20 01:20:15 2020
Slogan: Problem starting the module mod_shared_roster for host localhost 
 options: []
 error: undef
[{mod_shared_roster,start,[<<"localhost">>,[]],[]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,4,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{li
System version: Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]
Compiled: Sun May 17 03:40:44 2020
Taints: ets_cache,iconv,jid,stringprep,fxml_stream,fxml,p1_sha,fast_yaml,crypto,erl_tracer
Atoms: 21914
Calling Thread: scheduler:1
=scheduler:1
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: 
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: THR_PRGR_LATER_OP
Current Port: 
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 1
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: NONEMPTY_NORMAL | OUT_OF_WORK | HALFTIME_OUT_OF_WORK | NONEMPTY | EXEC
Current Process: <0.231.0>
Current Process State: Running
Current Process Internal State: ACT_PRIO_NORMAL | USR_PRIO_NORMAL | PRQ_PRIO_NORMAL | ACTIVE | RUNNING | TRAP_EXIT | ON_HEAP_MSGQ
Current Process Program counter: 0x00007fe7a2a3ffa0 (timer:sleep/1 + 80)
Current Process CP: 0x0000000000000000 (invalid)
Current Process Limited Stack Trace:
0x00007fe7a117fa38:SReturn addr 0xA1555C58 (gen_mod:start_module/4 + 3008)
0x00007fe7a117fa40:SReturn addr 0xA579CCA0 (lists:foreach/2 + 120)
0x00007fe7a117fa68:SReturn addr 0xA579CCA0 (lists:foreach/2 + 120)
0x00007fe7a117fa80:SReturn addr 0xA15546D0 (gen_mod:start_link/0 + 176)
0x00007fe7a117fa98:SReturn addr 0xA5784F08 (supervisor:do_start_child/2 + 280)
0x00007fe7a117faa8:SReturn addr 0xA5784828 (supervisor:start_children/3 + 128)
0x00007fe7a117fac8:SReturn addr 0xA5784248 (supervisor:init_children/2 + 224)
0x00007fe7a117faf0:SReturn addr 0xA5945328 (gen_server:init_it/2 + 112)
0x00007fe7a117fb08:SReturn addr 0xA5944BD0 (gen_server:init_it/6 + 280)
0x00007fe7a117fb20:SReturn addr 0xA5764300 (proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3 + 72)
0x00007fe7a117fb60:SReturn addr 0x74E758 (<terminate process normally>)
=scheduler:2
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: SLEEPING | POLL_SLEEPING | WAITING
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: 
Current Port: 
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 0
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: OUT_OF_WORK
Current Process: 
=memory
total: 34086872
processes: 7603192
processes_used: 7589856
system: 26483680
atom: 662433
atom_used: 654099
binary: 387144
code: 15169299
ets: 3073496
=hash_table:atom_tab
size: 19289
used: 13177
objs: 21913
depth: 7
=index_table:atom_tab
size: 22528
limit: 1048576
entries: 21914
=hash_table:module_code
size: 397
used: 266
objs: 394
depth: 5
=index_table:module_code
size: 1024
limit: 65536
entries: 394
=hash_table:export_list
size: 6421
used: 4751
objs: 8652
depth: 7
=index_table:export_list
size: 9216
limit: 524288
entries: 8652
=hash_table:export_list
size: 6421
used: 4741
objs: 8607
depth: 7
=hash_table:process_reg
size: 97
used: 71
objs: 116
depth: 4
=hash_table:fun_table
size: 3203
used: 2370
objs: 4015
depth: 7
=hash_table:node_table
size: 11
used: 1
objs: 1
depth: 1
=hash_table:dist_table
size: 11
used: 1
objs: 1
depth: 1
=allocated_areas
sys_misc: 72644
static: 527312
atom_space: 327760 319426
atom_table: 334673
module_table: 174456
export_table: 375708
export_list: 1522752
register_table: 892
fun_table: 25738
module_refs: 18960
loaded_code: 13051685
dist_table: 563
node_table: 251
bits_bufs_size: 0
bif_timer: 0
link_lh: 0
process_table: 3145728
port_table: 393216
ets_misc: 32768
=allocator:sys_alloc
option e: true
option m: libc
option tt: 131072
option tp: 0
=allocator:temp_alloc[0]
versions: 2.1 3.0
option e: true
option t: 3
option ramv: false
option sbct: 524288
option asbcst: 4145152
option rsbcst: 90
option rsbcmt: 80
option rmbcmt: 100
option mmbcs: 131072
option mmsbc: 256
option mmmbc: 18446744073709551615
option lmbcs: 10485760
option smbcs: 1048576
option mbcgs: 10
option acul: 0
option mbsd: 3
option as: gf
mbcs blocks: 0 4 4
mbcs blocks size: 0 8512 8512
mbcs carriers: 1 1 1
mbcs mseg carriers: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers: 1
mbcs carriers size: 131072 131072 131072
mbcs mseg carriers size: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 131072
sbcs blocks: 0 0 0
sbcs blocks size: 0 0 0
sbcs carriers: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers: 0
sbcs carriers size: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers size: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 0
temp_alloc calls: 2274
temp_free calls: 2274
temp_realloc calls: 0
mseg_alloc calls: 0
mseg_dealloc calls: 0
mseg_realloc calls: 0
sys_alloc calls: 1
sys_free calls: 0
sys_realloc calls: 0
=allocator:temp_alloc[1]
versions: 0.9 3.0
option e: true
option t: 3
option ramv: false
option sbct: 524288
option asbcst: 4145152
option rsbcst: 90
option rsbcmt: 80
option rmbcmt: 100
option mmbcs: 131072
option mmsbc: 256
option mmmbc: 18446744073709551615
option lmbcs: 10485760
option smbcs: 1048576
option mbcgs: 10
option acul: 0
option as: af
mbcs blocks: 0 5 5
mbcs blocks size: 0 423040 423040
mbcs carriers: 1 2 2
mbcs mseg carriers: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers: 1
mbcs carriers size: 131072 1179648 1179648
mbcs mseg carriers size: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 131072
sbcs blocks: 0 0 0
sbcs blocks size: 0 0 0
sbcs carriers: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers: 0
sbcs carriers size: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers size: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 0
temp_alloc calls: 186388
temp_free calls: 186388
temp_realloc calls: 1595
mseg_alloc calls: 4
mseg_dealloc calls: 4
mseg_realloc calls: 0
sys_alloc calls: 1
sys_free calls: 0
sys_realloc calls: 0
=allocator:temp_alloc[2]
versions: 0.9 3.0
option e: true
option t: 3
option ramv: false
option sbct: 524288
option asbcst: 4145152
option rsbcst: 90
option rsbcmt: 80
option rmbcmt: 100
option mmbcs: 131072
option mmsbc: 256
option mmmbc: 18446744073709551615
option lmbcs: 10485760
option smbcs: 1048576
option mbcgs: 10
option acul: 0
option as: af
mbcs blocks: 1 4 4
mbcs blocks size: 4104 29152 29152
mbcs carriers: 1 1 1
mbcs mseg carriers: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers: 1
mbcs carriers size: 131072 131072 131072
mbcs mseg carriers size: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 131072
sbcs blocks: 0 0 0
sbcs blocks size: 0 0 0
sbcs carriers: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers: 0
sbcs carriers size: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers size: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 0
temp_alloc calls: 14712
temp_free calls: 14711
temp_realloc calls: 674
mseg_alloc calls: 0
mseg_dealloc calls: 0
mseg_realloc calls: 0
sys_alloc calls: 1
sys_free calls: 0
sys_realloc calls: 0
=allocator:sl_alloc[0]
versions: 0.9 3.0
option e: true
option t: 3
option ramv: false
option sbct: 524288
option asbcst: 4145152
option rsbcst: 80
option rsbcmt: 80
option rmbcmt: 50
option mmbcs: 65536
option mmsbc: 256
option mmmbc: 18446744073709551615
option lmbcs: 5242880
option smbcs: 524288
option mbcgs: 10
option acul: 0
option as: aoffcbf
mbcs blocks: 1 183 183
mbcs blocks size: 520 49192 49192
mbcs carriers: 1 1 1
mbcs mseg carriers: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers: 1
mbcs carriers size: 65536 65536 65536
mbcs mseg carriers size: 0
mbcs sys_alloc carriers size: 65536
sbcs blocks: 0 0 0
sbcs blocks size: 0 0 0
sbcs carriers: 0 0 0
sbcs mseg carriers: 0
sbcs sys_alloc carriers: 0
sbcs carriers size: 0 0 0
```

Please help me find out what I am doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although I think your question can be answered as is there are few things I'd like to point out. Be specific in your title and description; I see a specific error in your posted log. Also there's no need for terminal screenshots; you did it great by posting the terminal output as text. Finally, there's a ``Crash dump`` file written to your log (last line of your terminal output); please add it (preferrably only the relevant part) to your question description – it may contain relevant information.

Comment: I'm going to do few edits to your question. However, the previously pointed out missing ``Crash dump`` should be added by you. Also, if you changed or tried something make sure add that specifically to your description; ``I tried to change hosts value of ejabberd.yml`` doesn't explain what you tried ;)

Comment: Also add which version of the ``ejabberd`` server you're using.

Comment: @IvoMori thanks for the feedback and edit, made the suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that it couldn't find the definition of function mod_shared_roster:start with two arguments. It couldn't find the file mod_shared_roster.beam

I can't help more, as you didn't indicate what ejabberd version you installed, using what method, on what operating system. Didn't comment if it worked correctly in the very first start, before modifying the configuration file.